# How do I test a JSON API?

Tags: php, python, laravel, tdd

I've got a JSON API implemented in Laravel/PHP, but it has no tests.. how do I properly test it? I've got a Swagger file.
I could manually write requests in Python or PHP (or C++) and manually check responses but there's got to be a better way. Is there a library that can help with this?
Ideally it'd record responses if an expected response isn't available yet such that next time it can compare the response to the expected response.
It'd also be nice if it generates invalid requests to verify those are handled properly as well.

Comment: you can use chrome plugin POSTMAN for testing api.https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If your API is already online, you can use: https://www.hurl.it/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chrome [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) and it's pretty good. I have been using for the past couple of yrs for API integration and others. It shows the JSON response in a proper readable format

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion postman is the best tool for testing api paths
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en